# Find first integral of differential equation system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the system

$$\dot{x} = x$$

$$\dot{y} = y$$

Then, I can get $\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dy}{y}$, which means $\ln{\frac{x}{y}} = c$.

Hence, I think the first integral of this system is $F(x, y) = \ln{\frac{x}{y}}$.

But the answer is $F(x, y) = \frac{x}{y}$ or $F(x, y) = \frac{y}{x}$.

I cannot understand why I am wrong, can anyone explain the difference?

Comment: If $\ln \dfrac xy=c$ then $\dfrac xy=e^c=C$ or $\dfrac yx=1/C$.

Answer (score 2):

You're not wrong.  The answers are equivalent.

If $\ln \dfrac xy$ is a constant, then $\dfrac xy$ is a constant related to it.

In particular, if $\ln \dfrac xy=c,$ then $\dfrac xy=e^c=C,$ or $\dfrac yx=1/C$.